# Truncated distribution in R with percentage above certain value?

Tags: r, distribution, truncate

I need a random distribution with 300 samples that vary between values of 0 and approx. 150.

Additionally, 20% of the samples should have values above 50.

I have tried something like this:

```
# my specifications
n <- 300 # fixed
percentage_above <- 0.2 # fixed
threshold <- 50 # fixed
lower <- 0 # fixed
upper <- 150 # fixed
m <- 35 # change
sd <- 45 # change

# truncated normal
samples <- rtruncnorm(n, a = lower, b = upper, m = m, sd = sd)
sum(samples > threshold) / n
```

Depending on how I vary `m` and `sd`, I get closer to the required 20%. But is there an easier way to get what I need?

PS: the underlying distribution does not have to be normal

Comment: What distribution DO you need? If it really doesn't matte then just sample 60 values in the 50-150 range and 240 in the 0-50 range then combine.

Comment: something like @Allans options below looks good

Comment: I don't think you should name it as "truncated" since you have no info where it is truncated from. Better to rephrase it as a "bounded distribution"

Comment: thank you for the comment and sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option that is based on an exponential distribution. It will generate `n` random numbers, of which the given proportion `prop` will be greater than the given `threshold`. The proportion will be exact if `n` times the proportion is a whole number.

Although it uses a fixed random seed, it will put R's random number generator back into the state it was when the function was called:

```r
rnum <- function(n, prop = 0.2, threshold = 50, upper = 150) {
  RS <- .GlobalEnv$.Random.seed
  fun <- function(p) {
    set.seed(1)
    x <- rexp(n + 1)^p
    x <- upper * x/max(x)
    x <- x[-which.max(x)]
    abs(sum(x > threshold)/n - prop)
  }
  p <- optimize(fun, c(0, 10))$minimum
  set.seed(1)
  x <- rexp(n + 1)^p
  .GlobalEnv$.Random.seed <- RS
  x <- upper * x/max(x)
  x[-which.max(x)]
}
```

We can see the output as a histogram:

```r
x <- rnum(300)

hist(x)
```

[image]

And we can demonstrate that exactly 20% of these numbers are above 50:

```r
length(which(x > 50))
#> [1] 60
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: To see the final proportion there's also `mean(x > 50)`. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't specify what is the distribution, you can construct it like below

```
set.seed(0)

n <- 300
p <- 0.2
r <- sample(c(runif(n * p, 50, 150), runif(n * (1 - p), 0, 50)))
```

and you see the CDF curve like below

```
plot(ecdf(r))
abline(h = 1-p, v = 50)
```

[image]